# Can I power my PI via USB if I Disable USB?

Tags: usb, power, usb-power, power-management

I learnt that I can disable the USB circuitry with this command:

```sh
echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Does doing this disable USB power too? Or just data/connectivity?

I would test this but I only have USB power available and don't want to be stuck with a bricked Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this disable USB power too? Or just support for USB data/devices?

The latter. No driver or any form of software is required for the 5V system to work, nor can it be turned off with software without additional hardware.